# ASPX forms to Database

Tags: asp.net, database

I am new to ASP.NET, and I am trying to create a 'contact us' form which sends an email at submission as well storing the data in a database.

I am pretty comfortable with a basic form to email setup - but having trouble with the database part of it.

Please let me know if you have ever done this, or if you could provide any information that would assist me with this task.

this is my default.aspx.cs for SMTP mail http://pastie.org/2278140
this is my default.aspx http://pastie.org/2278142

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Have you made any attempts to do this? or are you just asking the question before looking into how to do it?

Start at the very begining.

http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/5-working-with-data